What am I doing wrong if people repeat their original offers and requests despite me declining them?
Problem
I've noticed a common pattern in my interactions. A person—whether a coworker, relative, or acquaintance—makes an offer or request. I politely and respectfully decline, explaining why it's unacceptable, and usually offer an alternative or try to negotiate. The person doesn't argue, negotiate, or engage in any discussion; they simply walk away. Later, they come back with the same offer or request, as if I hadn't explained anything. I decline again, and this cycle continues, sometimes for several rounds, without any progress towards a deal.
Example 1
A couple of years ago, a potential employer in a European country offered me a job. I respectfully declined, explaining that my current job was better for me both career-wise and financially. I also mentioned that I would consider his offer if it included a substantially higher pay. He didn't seem offended and didn't counter my arguments.
However, since then, he has been emailing me twice a year with the same offer (adjusted merely for inflation) and asking if I've changed my mind. Each time, he emphasizes various benefits of working for him but doesn't directly address my reasons for refusal. I've always responded with a polite no, briefly repeating my reasons and inviting him to discuss the pay, but he ignores that.
I believe we could negotiate a mutually beneficial deal, but he appears to be blindly stuck to his original offer and unwilling to discuss his reasons for not changing it.
Example 2
My parents told me they plan to leave their entire estate to my brother because they believe he will need it more (see this post for details). As a result, I stopped talking with them, leaving email as the only option for contact. I stopped giving them psychological support and any kind of advice. I explained that any interaction with them would remind me of their utterly unfair decision. I also told them to turn to my brother for any help.
Despite my explanation, my parents have been bombarding me with requests to restore the relationship and help them with advice. My mother has a complicated medical condition, with doctors offering conflicting opinions and different treatment options. Unable to navigate the medical information on their own, my parents want my advice. I have reiterated my reason for refusal multiple times, but they just ignore it and repeat their requests.
Without my advice, my mother underwent a surgery that later proved to be unnecessary, and her condition substantially deteriorated as a result. Even now, struggling with aggravated health issues and needing my advice and support even more, my parents are still unwilling to reconsider or even discuss their decision to leave everything to my brother. They don't challenge my view that their decision is unfair. Instead, they send emails like, "Think how much time and effort we invested in you when you were a child," and "How could you not want to help even a little bit." They have also tried to change my mind by involving relatives and even a coworker of mine (by sending her a message).
Additional remarks
These examples are not isolated exceptions. Even a close friend repeatedly asks me to rent a flat together to save money, unable to accept my reason for saying no (which is that privacy is important to me).
I must be doing something wrong, but I have no idea what it is. I've asked a couple of friends, but they couldn't provide useful feedback.
Question
What am I doing wrong? How do I stop people from repeating the same offer or request over and over again? How do I make them understand that their original offer or request is unacceptable to me, no matter how many times they repeat it? How do I make them take my reasons for refusal seriously? How do I get them to choose between engaging in a real discussion or negotiation and simply leaving me alone?

Example 2 doesn't fit in. Your parents aren't comparable to some spamming recruiter or a friend who can't let go of her idea. They haven't made a request or an offer that can be negotiated. They are appealing to your love or sense of duty to reestablish contact with them. Even if you're justified in refusing (hard to judge), they have essentially lost a child and it would be unnatural for them to just accept that.

I would add a frame challenge to this question: you are approaching life as a negotiation, and your surroundings do not agree. Neither the family nor the flat situation sound to me like negotiations, why would the other side even be aware that they "need to improve their offering"?

@Stefan The common factor in the situation with the parents and other situations is that the other party knows why I can't give them what they want - and, consequently, what they have to change - but they refuse to do so or even discuss it. I've told my parents many times I can't talk with them because I can't bear the unfairness of their decision about the inheritance. I've told them many times they have to change it if they want to talk with me. But they simply ignore that. They refuse to even explain why changing their decision about the inheritance isn't an option for them.

@Stefan They don't even say it's not an option for them. They plainly ignore my reason, appealing to my love and sense of duty over and over again

@Stefan And that is precisely the same thing that the potential employer does. He ignores my reason for declining his offer. He refuses to even explain why changing the compensation package isn't an option. He doesn't even say it's not an option. He plainly ignores my reason, pointing out various benefits of working for him (which are very secondary to me).

@xLeitix Yes, there's nothing to negotiate in the situation with the friend. I've told her I need a separate unit to fully relax after work. But she is always like "come on, imagine how much money we can save." This is getting very annoying. In the situation with the parents, I've told them many times they have to change their decision about the inheritance if they want to talk with me, because I can't bear the unfairness of their decision. So, we could negotiate what share I will get, but they refuse to even talk about it.

With the friend, you did make a mistake. You gave reasons why you don’t want to share a home. Next time  you just say you don’t want to do this. No reasons. Just you don’t want to. So nothing that can be argued with.

With the parents and no inheritance, you are angry. Tell them you are angry. Tell them nothing will be discussed as long as you are angry, and you will be angry as long as you are not in their will. They have all kinds of reasons in their mind why what they are doing is right, and you cannot convince them otherwise. But you can convince them you are angry.

But would you really want your parents to buy your affection by changing their will, if they are not convinced that their decision was unfair?

@Stefan They don't challenge my notion that their decision is unfair. They refuse to discuss their decision, and they refuse to discuss their refusal to discuss their decision. I don't see it as selling my affection for changing the will. Being part of the family and getting a share of the inheritance are inseparable things for me, for families pass their estate from generations to generations. Real estate prices are ridiculously high nowadays, and excluding a child from the distribution of the real estate earned by the previous generations is tantamount to excluding the child from the family.

Stefan, it’s difficult. What they did sounds nasty to me. I have children, and excluding one from their inheritance would be a very nasty thing to do, and I would expect them to be angry. Somehow it seems she never managed to explain this to the parents. And it’s not “buying her affections”. It seems more like “decent human behaviour if you don’t want to destroy the relationship”.

@gnasher729 I agree it's difficult, but if Mitsuko's parents grudgingly meet her halfway after a tough negotiation because they want something from her, I don't see how that saves the relationship. She'd still know that they would have preferred to give her nothing. If she could convince her parents that they were wrong, it would be different. But that can't be done by treating it as a negotiation. That's what I wanted to say with my comment.

That doesn't save their relationship (most likely it cannot be saved with money, only with a genuine attempt of seeing her point of view, which is hard for some people), but if she gets part of the inheritance that is a success.

Why do you repeat yourself and over-explain instead of saying "We discussed this." Not "We discussed this, and I told you already ..." You give away your power when you keep revisiting stuff, unless your word carries no weight and needs justifying each time. Does it?

What you describe has nothing related to IPS per se, but to psychology, and is more of a mild form of resilience and "level 1 unconscious gaslighting" with a little bit of coercion and a little bit of scapegoating:

Resilience is the process and outcome of successfully adapting to difficult or challenging life experiences, especially through mental, emotional, and behavioral flexibility and adjustment to external and internal demands.

You wonder 1. what you did in order for you to face this kind of behaviour (repeatedly asking), and 2. why people do what they do and ask again. Answers are pretty small and straightforward:

Nothing special.
Has the situation evolved?

Now, if you analyse the 2 situations, you'll see a common pattern. People want to know if you changed your mind.
As for the employer, it's a pretty standard behaviour: they keep in touch and want you to know that they're still available, letting you know that, if you changed your mind, the position is there for you to negociate. They expect an answer only if you're interested. Don't try and negociate or make your point(s) or convince them, it's a plain and simple YES/NO.
As for your family, it's the same thing: did time make its office and make you change your mind? By asking again, people (consciously or not), want to sow the seeds of doubt in your mind. Maybe you have changed your mind (or will), maybe you'll feel guilty after refusing once again, maybe you won't have enough strength to say no once more...
You can identify this behaviour as early as kindergarden-time, when toddlers repeatedly say the same thing, thinking you'll change your mind just because they say it, and say it, and say it again. People behave like this because "no" doesn't seem to be an answer. They keep pushing with the hope that you'll change your mind.
You did nothing wrong, it's human nature to behave like they do.
Now, as the IPS answer to that, experience taught me that the only two ways to deal with it are: 1. quietly and firmly stand your ground 2. ignore them or their request, depending on the situation (if personal or professional) and the relationship.
In your case #1, as it's a professional, not big deal not to answer. Keep in touch only if you're interested in something they can do for you. Everybody is doing that in real life, it's part of the game, they expect that. About the family business, it's way much touchy...
As already said in answers to your previous question, dealing with your parents can be done either way: the one you're actually using, or another one (there's always "another way" I guess). Your call. No matter what they ask/expect, it's your choice. Mine was to stand my ground up to my tolerance level. Once reached, I would stop calling/answering/visiting until the heat is off, and (almost) everyone had chilled out. It sometimes took years before I talk to some persons of my family. But family business is always different for every individual. I chose to stand my ground with always the same answer and argument. I chose not to answer their question when asked again and again. I chose to dodge the bullets anytime they would fire the same arguments. It is then your resilience. It didn't help that much for years, until time has done its office, and my resilience was "the last man standing". Did I do something wrong? I don't think so. I just didn't let them push until they "win" (for lack of a better word, as there's no winner in these tough family cases).
So, to clear your points one by one (with a "most probably" warning ahead of each answer), and as I've witnessed/suffered enough of these through decades:

How do I stop people from repeating the same offer or request over and over again? -> you can't (unless you burn all bridges)

How do I make them understand that their original offer or request is unacceptable to me, no matter how many times they repeat it? -> you can't (unless you burn all bridges) because what matters to them is them asking, not you answering.

How do I make them take my reasons for refusal seriously? -> you can't (unless you burn all bridges)

How do I get them to choose between engaging in a real discussion or negotiation and simply leaving me alone? -> you can't (unless you burn all bridges)


As you can see, it's not something you can really control, it's human behaviour, and people expect you to modify your stance/opinion. The way to handle it is your choice, as well as the possible consequences on the relationship.

Not everything in life is a negotiation. Not every time that I ask you for something am I willing to ask differently, or turn my "please give me X" into a "please trade me X if I give you Y" offering. Sometimes "please give me X" means "I really want X and I hope you will give it to me", nothing more, nothing less.
I treat almost nothing as a negotiation. Someone asks me for something, I say "sure!" or "no thankyou" and that's that. They don't ask me over and over. When I say "well I would but" or "no unless" or "only if" they go on and on requesting the same thing without addressing my but, unless, or if. It's like they hear "this decision isn't quite settled yet and you can change it if you say the right thing to me".
Why do they keep asking?
The potential employer has a budget for a position, and believes you're a good fit for it. They will not (it is clear) change that budget. This doesn't oblige you to take the job, but understand: they don't have to come back with a higher salary, even if they could be sure you would take the job if they did. They have the budget they have.
The parents desperately need help. They are not competent at navigating the medical decisions they need to make. They are probably not also super competent at parenting from your account of them. But they need help. So they are calling "help!". You are not obliged to help them any more than you are obliged to take a job that pays less than you are worth, but they, I am quite sure, do not understand why you will not help, and are not going to change their will to get that help even if you somehow got across to them that your position (demand?) is that they do so. Instead they remind you of your societal obligation and hope you will do "your duty". They have few other options.
The person who wants to share a flat is probably similar. They want to live away from their current situation, but can't afford it and would like to save rent by sharing with someone. So they ask. They call "help!". They can't make you a better offer or otherwise persuade you. They hope you change your position over time, because hope is the only strategy they have in this situation.
My advice to you is to stop treating these requests as the start of a negotiation where you say "no" or "no, unless..." or "only if you..." and each of these replies interchangeably results in the person improving their offer or moving towards your position. Instead, treat them as requests and reply accordingly.

No thankyou
I cannot do that because [half a sentence that does not contain any suggestion they can fix this]
That doesn't work for me
It's still no on that one, sorry
Nothing has changed, I'm not going to do that

Example for the job "no thankyou, I prefer my current job to what you are offering." Example for the parents "I cannot get wrapped up in the medical issues while we have unresolved emotional pain, my head does not work properly to do the work it would require while I'm being reminded of our issues." Example for the room-mate, "no thankyou, but I will let you know if any of our mutual friends mention they might be available."
On the matter of your parents, if you can actually do the medical stuff but want to make them change their minds, I recommend you do it. They clearly need your help and are doing it all wrong. They may never change their minds; if you're able to help them anyway that would be good. Sure, being competent and capable is exactly why they have told you they won't be helping you, and that's wrong of them, but that has happened and is over. If they were going to change it, they would have already. It's not a negotiating point or a bargaining chip. Set it aside and consider and "am I actually capable of helping?" If it's no, then it's no. Period. Not "unless you change your will" just no. If it's yes, then consider yes.

Giving reasons to the parents is not going to help. Better “I am angry that you disinherited me. I won’t help you because I’m angry. Ask your son for help.”  Because that is exactly her reason. That’s what I would expect my daughter to do in the same situation.

"but that has happened and is over" No, it's not over, for my parents can still change their decision. They haven't irreversibly transferred their estate to my brother. They haven't signed any documents whatsoever.

If your parents change their mind, @Mitsuko, that will be a different event. Their decision to leave all the money to your brother has happened. You have asked repeatedly for it to be changed, and they have not changed it. You expect people to "get it" and stop just asking you to change your mind, but you don't seem to do the same about your parents. You can't make them change their minds. Once you are standing on that ground, what will you do going forward? Will you help, not as a bargaining chip, but just to help? Or will you not? Both are valid choices in their own right.

I agree with the previous posters that you must distinguish what you can change from what you can't, and the distinctions between standard behaviors (recruiters) vs. family crises. But you can steer the conversation differently.

If you once explained your motives, if people ignore them, they do not deserve to hear them again (but read below).

One way to discourage people who annoy you is to seriously and unemotionally respond with the same thing and nothing else. E.g. "I don't like it when you do this".
You can apply this to 1 and 3 (the friend) in a modified way. For instance, just re-forward your original reply, again and again. Eventually they will get it that the conversation has ended.

Don't be defensive (explaining) but lead (ask them). It seems you may have done this already in examples 1 and 2, not sure how from your question? Example 1. Instead of your first reply, explanations, maybe counter offer, second time be brief "offer me X" with no explanation. Then they are on the spot. If they send the same offer again, you can send the same answer (adjusted for inflation).
With the friend who wants to move with you "find an apartment with 2 bathrooms/2 separate entrances" whatever your privacy requires. It does not matter if such an apartment does not exist or is not affordable; she is being absurd in ignoring your motives, you can be a bit too (never over the top, you want to de-escalate your disagreement and stay friends).


The situation with your parents is far more painful and stressful and it's not sure that such a policy can fix it, but my suggestion, if you can do it, is this. You first explain (or explained) your motives and feelings. Afterwards what's left is to control the discussion and stay constructive.  and positive inasmuch as possible. Can you propose something that's more fair to you? For example, assure your parents that your care for them and the brother is worth more than the money they will leave him?
In any case, every time your point of view is ignored, return with your proposal, the same proposal. But be nice; for example, state that you love your family, but that you believe plan X is the best one. And stick with it. This way you leave the communication open, but you refuse the conversations where your point of view is not respected.
In summary, you can't stop people from asking you the same thing, but you can stay polite and even nice, and in the same time effectively close the conversations you don't want to have.
I wish you good luck with your family situation.
